# Use a variable as an object key in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm having trouble constructing an object. I've got a string (called "SKU" for this example) and it's coming through `action` as `action.name`.

I have everything available in the reducer function but I need to change the hardcoded `SKU` to action.name, but obviously that's not possible in JS. I've tried `action.name`, `action['name']` and other variations and I'm stuck.

What is the work around? Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Here's some code so you can see what's going on:

*function that fires when date changes...*

```
handleChange(date) {
  this.props.addDate(date, this.props.dashboardName);
}
```

*mapDispatch which is connected at the bottom of the component export...*

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    addDate: (date, name) => dispatch({
      type: 'ACTION_DASHBOARD_ADD_DATE',
      date,
      name
    })
  };
};
```

*action creator...*

```
export function DashboardDate() {
  return {
    type: ACTION_DASHBOARD_ADD_DATE
  };
}
```

*case in the switch of the reducer...*

```
case ACTION_DASHBOARD_ADD_DATE: {
      var filter = {};
      filter[action.name] = action.date;
      return {
        ...state,
        dashboard: {
          ...state.dashboard,
          // Below SKU needs to be the value of action.name
          SKU: {
            // Below too, action.name
            ...state.dashboard.SKU,
            filter
          }
        }
      };
    }
```

Comment: did either of our answers help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure where in your code you want to have the `sku` appear, but you can create an object with a computed property name like this:

```
const obj = {
    [action.name]: action.payload
};

console.log(obj); // { "sku": "abcd" }
```

Computed property names are an ES2015 (ES6) feature.

Answer (score 6):

Use [action.name] (syntax for computed key)

```
case ACTION_DASHBOARD_ADD_DATE: {
  var filter = {};
  filter[action.name] = action.date;
  return {
    ...state,
    dashboard: {
      ...state.dashboard,
      [action.name]: {
        ...state.dashboard.SKU,
        filter
      }
    }
  };
}
```