# In React / Redux, how to call the same fetch twice in componentDidMount, setting 2 state variables with results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The title is wordy, however a short / simple example will go a long ways in explaining my question. I have the following start to a component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { fetchGames } from '../../path-to-action';

class TeamsApp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            oldGames: [],
            newGames: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchGames('1617'));
        this.setState({ oldGames: this.props.teamGameData });
        this.props.dispatch(fetchGames('1718'));
        this.setState({ newGames: this.props.teamGameData });
    }

    ...
    ...
}

function mapStateToProps(reduxState) {
    return {
        teamGameData: reduxState.GamesReducer.sportsData
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TeamsApp);
```

I would like the action / reducer that corresponds with `fetchGames()` and `gamesReducer` to be called twice when the component mounts. This action / reducer grabs some sports data, and I am trying to grab data for two separate seasons (the '1617' season and the '1718' season). The `fetchGames()` is built correctly to handle the season parameter.

With the current setup, the states aren't being set, and my linter is throwing an error `Do not use setState in componentDidMount`.

Can I pass a callback to this.props.dispatch that takes the results of the `fetchGames()` (the teamGameData prop), and sets the oldGames / newGames states equal to this object?

Any help with this is appreciated!

Edit: if i simply remove the this.setState()'s, then my `teamGameData` prop simply gets overridden with the second `this.props.dispatch()` call...

Edit 2: I'm not 100% sure at all if having the 2 state variables (oldGames, newGames) is the best approach. I just need to call this.props.dispatch(fetchGames('seasonid')) twice when the component loads, and have the results as two separate objects that the rest of the component can use.

Edit 3: I have the following part of my action:

```
export const fetchSportsDataSuccess = (sportsData, season) => ({
    type: FETCH_NBA_TEAM_GAME_SUCCESS,
    payload: { sportsData, season }
});
```

and the following case in my reducer:

```
case FETCH_NBA_TEAM_GAME_SUCCESS:
console.log('payload', action.payload);
return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    sportsData: action.payload.sportsData
};
```

and the console.log() looks like this now:

```
payload
{ sportsData: Array(2624), season: "1718" }
```

but i am not sure how to use the season ID to create a key in the return with this season's data....

Edit 4: found solution to edit 3 - [Use a variable as an object key in reducer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051403/use-a-variable-as-an-object-key-in-reducer) - thanks all for help on this, should be able to take it from here!

Comment: Why are you using Redux for this if you just want to use it as local component state? Am I missing something?

Comment: I use redux for all of my app's data flow.

Comment: I don't have a great answer for your question. I created the 2 state variables but am not 100% sure that saving the props as state is the best approach.

Comment: Then why store the data in the state of the component? why not in redux instead

Comment: All I know is that calling this.props.dispatch(fetchGames()) twice overwrites my teamGameData prop... if there was a way to have two props for this, that would be good too i guess

Comment: Alright, interesting. I personally think of Redux as a database in the browser to store data that might be of use in multiple parts of the app. If you just need game data for the ids `1617` and `1718` in this particular component, I don't see the use of having Redux take care of it.

Comment: if you need two props, store the data of each call in a separate key in redux. That way it wont be overridden.

Comment: im not sure how to store data of each call in separate key in redux - will look into this.

Comment: is reduxState.GamesReducer.sportsData a key? and you're suggesting i have something like reduxState.GamesReducer.sportsData2 as well?

Comment: Send the ID you accept while dispatching the action, as a payload with the action, in the reducer. Then in the reducer, use this ID as a key to store the data in redux

Comment: will give this a try

Comment: @AnmolMahatpurkar one last Q - I am able to send the ID into the reducer, but not sure how to use the ID as a key to store the data... will make edit to the post but could use help to get this last part finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Copying data from the redux store to one's component state is an anti-pattern**

Instead, you should modify your redux store, for example using an object to store data, so you'll be able to store datas for multiples seasons :

```
sportsData: {
    '1617': { ... },
    '1718': { ... },
}
```

This way you'll be able to fetch both seasons in the same time :

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const seasons = ['1718', '1617'];
    const promises = seasons.map(fetchGames);
    Promise.all(promises).catch(…);
}
```

And connect them both :

```
// you can use props here too
const mapStateToProps = (reduxState, props) => ({
    // hardcoded like you did
    oldGames: reduxState.GamesReducer.sportsData['1617'],
    // or using some props value, why not
    newGames: reduxState.GamesReducer.sportsData[props.newSeason],
};
```

Or connect the store as usual and go for the keys:

```
const mapStateToProps = (reduxState, props) => ({
    games: reduxState.GamesReducer.sportsData,
};
…
render() {
  const oldGame = this.props.games[1718];
  const newGame = this.props.games[1718];
  …
}
```

**Redux is you single source of truth**, always find a way to put everything you need in Redux instead of copying data in components

Comment: yes thank you. will create a new post if i cannot update the actions / reducers correctly, working on it now.